# Text only displaying as bold in Firefox and Safari, not Chrome

Tags: html, css

As stated in the title. I have some text that has the CSS `font-weight: bold;` and it's only working in Firefox and Safari (not sure about IE as I have a mac and haven't tested it yet). In Chrome it just seems to add a bit of spacing between the individual letters. The font is Open Sans and the size is `13px`.

HTML:

```
<ul class= "pull-right" id= "right-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html" class= "current-page">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="club-info.html">Club Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
    <li><a href="finding-us.html">Finding Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="about-bjj.html">About BJJ</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.current-page {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added it now.

Comment: Where are you getting the font from? Did you use the Google Font API? It would be helpful if you could post your code in a fiddle so we could modify it ourselves.

Comment: please add the code where you have added the font

Comment: works fine on chrome/mac **with** the custom font from google: http://jsfiddle.net/S93F9/

Comment: I have used the font from google fonts and I copied all the stuff exactly. I can't seem to make a fiddle that actually ends up looking how my page looks, sorry.

Comment: I just copied and pasted  PeterVR's link to the font and it now works. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Chrome is concerned, a page served as HTTPS should not be calling a resource served as HTTP. Chrome isn't picky about when things are the other way around, so it will happily retrieve an HTTPS resource via a page served as HTTP. Solutions:

**Option 1** - match the protocols

Make sure you always call the https version of your Google Webfont URL. For example:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700'
 rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**Option 2** - don't specify the protocol

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700'
 rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: If this were the issue, why would it affect bold typeface only? We do not know what the real problem was. It’s possible that Open Sans was not actually used at all, but the question refers to bold text only.

Comment: chrome must not be loading any font at all, not only the bold typeface. it must be displaying the default font.

Comment: @freefaller edited :P

Comment: Unidioted :-) I have done a rollback for you, to remove the edit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply

```
.current-page {font-weight :bolder; }
```

instead of using the css

```
.current-page {font-weight :bold; }
```

I have had this problem as well and that is how I sorted it.

Or you can try

for semi-bold

```
font-weight:600;
```

for extra bold (800)

```
font-weight:800;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

before font-weight: bold;

Edited to add... if you are using th Google API then you also must reference the CSS link

```
<link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:400,700'; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Otherwise the bold font won't download

Comment: Why would it work in FF and Safari?

Comment: Good question... everybody creating their own standards maybe?  In any case, the quickest solution is to wrap the A tags in a set of strong tags

Comment: Strong tags didn't work either. In any case I've sorted it now. I had to match the protocols on the link to google fonts.